# Creating a path from a child row and its "parents"

Tags: sql-server

i have a table that contains 3 fields:

```
idArticle (int)
idParent (int)
idAlias (nvarchar[255])
```

i would like to add to that table a computed column,
that will return the `Path` to the article.
That is, assuming we have two rows:

```
1,0,"First"
2,1,"Second"
```

if we run the function on the second row,
i want `Path` in that case to return `First/Second`

from what i read, i would need to create a `Scalar Function` to apply as the computed field,
feeding it with the `idArticle`.

my SQL skills are pretty limited to basic queries and i do not know how to approach this.
Anyone out there to the rescue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First I create a recursive inline TVF function (not a scalar function - for performance reasons) in order to get the path for some article `@idArticle` thus:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetArticlePath(@idArticle INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH CteRecursive 
AS
(
    SELECT  cld.idArticle, cld.idParent, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), cld.idAlias) AS ArticlePath
    FROM    dbo.Article cld
    WHERE   cld.idArticle = @idArticle

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  prt.idArticle, prt.idParent, prt.idAlias + N'\' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), cld.ArticlePath) AS ArticlePath
    FROM    dbo.Article prt INNER JOIN CteRecursive cld ON cld.idParent = prt.idArticle

)
SELECT  *
FROM    CteRecursive rec
WHERE   rec.idParent = 0;
GO
```

2) Sample usage:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.GetArticlePath(2) f
/*
idArticle   idParent    ArticlePath
----------- ----------- ------------
1           0           First\Second
*/
```

3) I would use this function with an `UPDATE` statement thus:

```
UPDATE  a
SET     ArticlePath = p.ArticlePath
FROM    dbo.Article a
OUTER APPLY dbo.GetArticlePath(a.idArticle) p
WHERE   a.idArticle = 2;

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Article;
/*
idArticle   idParent    idAlias  articlePath
----------- ----------- -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           0           First    NULL
2           1           Second   First\Second
*/
```

Comment: This looks great, some clarification please (so i could understand)
q: is there a reason i should not use a computed column?
q: can i create an update trigger instead?

Comment: I wouldn't use for this a computed column (`ArticlePath AS (scalar function) [PERSISTED]`). Why ? Because a scalar function will block parallelism on this table. How many parents do you expect (on average) to have a leaf row ? A regular column (`ArticlePath NVARCHAR(max lenght)` with a well written trigger could be a solution.

Comment: i believe the maximum path depth would be at max 30.

Comment: Well in this case, a regular column with updated by a stored procedure or by a trigger could be a *solution* if `idAlias` values aren't changing frequently. Otherwise calling `dbo.GetArticlePath` for every article which must be displayed could be a better solution. You have to test these solutions yourself to see which is the best for you.